# What means "(? symbol? name)"?

Tags: list, syntax, scheme, racket

I had problem even in choosing a title for this question. Please feel free to edit it.

I got this Scheme code and did not understand this block.

```
(define (func b)
 (match b
   [(list (? symbol? x) rhs) ...
```

The trouble part is (? symbol? x). I guess it's a comparator of some sort, but I didn't find anything about it anywhere! It's hard to search it, since I don't know how to name this command.

I would like to get at least its name, further explanations are appreciated. =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it!

It's a specific case of (match ...) syntax. Found it here: [Pattern Matching](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1730/2008/Manual/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._scheme/match..ss%29._match%29%29)

More specific:

> (match val-expr clause ...)
>
> clause = [pat expr ...+] 
>   | [pat (=> id) expr ...+]

Where pat is

> pat ::= id                  [match anything, bind identifier]
>           (...)
>           | (? expr pat ...)  [match if (expr value) and pat]

So I was kinda right: it's checking if x is a symbol.

I was lucky! Please complete this topic!
Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's a description of what you've asked about.  It's a facility that is specific to [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), and you can find the updated documentation [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html).

Comment: When you say, "please complete this topic", I'm guessing that you're suggesting that the question should be closed.  The best way to do this is to click on the outlined "check" next to your own answer; this will show that the question has been answered.

Comment: @Eli: Yes, good point, it's Racket's. But I saw they're kinda equivalent, as you can see in [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=match#(form._((lib._racket/match..rkt)._match) and comparing with my original link.

@John Clements: I meant to put more references, not for closing the question.

Comment: @John Clements: I meant to put more references, not for closing the question.